# Can I use a loop to optimize my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to optimize my code to be more efficient and easier to read. I have some combined if-statements, which I think could be better, if they are transformed to for-loops, I'm just not sure how to do this?

This is my code:

```
    if (starportSelected){
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles.indexOf('transport')>-1 && cashBalance>=vehicles.list["transport"].cost){
            $("#transportbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles.indexOf('scout-tank')>-1 && cashBalance>=vehicles.list["scout-tank"].cost){
            $("#scouttankbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles.indexOf('heavy-tank')>-1 &&cashBalance>=vehicles.list["heavy-tank"].cost){
            $("#heavytankbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles.indexOf('harvester')>-1 && cashBalance>=vehicles.list["harvester"].cost){
            $("#harvesterbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.aircraft.indexOf('chopper')>-1 && cashBalance>=aircraft.list["chopper"].cost){
            $("#chopperbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements.aircraft.indexOf('wraith')>-1 && cashBalance>=aircraft.list["wraith"].cost){
            $("#wraithbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }   
    }
```

I think first step would be to create two arrays, one for vehicles and one for aircrafts like this:

```
    var vehicles = ['transport', 'scout.tank', 'heavy-tank', 'harvester'];
    var aircraft = ['chopper', 'wraith'];
```

But how to take the rest of the code and change it to for-loop seems like a hard case for me.
All help and explanation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: if you have two arrays you will have to iterate through them. It seems like you your code you will need a nested for loop for vehicles and in it for aircraft. This is O(n^2) which is not great. 
Indexing a specific location in a hash table (which I am assuming you have have hash table will take O(1) per look up, which in total can take O(n) if you have n elements and go through all of them 

can you explain what your code is trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need 2 specific arrays here ? Why not club into a single object ?

Comment: You should alias repeated object access if you care about perf. `var foo = game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles;` and then `foo.indexOf('blah')`

Comment: In a game I have an object named startport. When the starport is selected by the player, it will be possible to select either vehicles or aircrafts in a sidebar menu, as long as the player has sufficient funds. The code is working as it is now, but I believe it could be better with some kind of loop, I'm just not sure how to write it?

Comment: @JaredSmith I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredSmith But then again, would that matter in a loop?

Comment: @Sushanth-- `game.currentLevel.requirements.aircraft.indexOf` and `game.currentLevel.requirements.vehicles.indexOf` are to different lines.

Comment: Yes it matters in a loop. With every iteration it has to go 4 steps up the scope resolution chain instead of one. Whether you write out the loop by hand or have the computer iterate through it for you its still the same number of accesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you have `"vehicles"` and `"aircraft"` types, with multiple values for each.

As such, I'd create an object of types to arrays of values.

Because you're also using a variable named `vehicles` and `aircraft`, you'll want to reference those in a separate object so that you can look them up with a string.

```
var lists = {
    vehicles: vehicles,
    aircraft: aircraft
}

var obj = {
    vehicles: ["transport", "scout-tank", "heavy-tank", "harvester"],
    aircraft: ["chopper", "wraith"]
};
```

Then use an outer and inner loop.

```
//        v---("vehicles" or "aircraft")
for (var type in obj) { //      v---("transport", "scout-tank", "chopper", etc...)
    obj[type].forEach(function(val) {
        if(game.currentLevel.requirements[type].indexOf(val)>-1 && 
                     cashBalance >= lists[type].list[val].cost) {
            $("#" + val.replace("-", "") + "button").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

Notice also that I had to replace the hyphen in the ID selector, since it wasn't used as part of the ID.

---

The two objects at the top could be combined into a single one if you wish:

```
var obj = {
    vehicles: {
        list: vehicles,
        values: ["transport", "scout-tank", "heavy-tank", "harvester"]
    },
    aircraft: {
        list: aircraft,
        values: ["chopper", "wraith"]
    }
};
```

Then adjust the loop references accordingly.

I've also cached the objects for performance, as Jared noted above.

```
for (var type in obj) {
    var list = obj[type].list;
    var requirements = game.currentLevel.requirements[type];

    obj[type].values.forEach(function(val) {
        if(requirements.indexOf(val)>-1 && cashBalance >= list[val].cost) {
            $("#" + val.replace("-", "") + "button").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

---

To make it even more efficient than the original, we'll drop some of the jQuery calls.

```
for (var type in obj) {
    var list = obj[type].list;
    var requirements = game.currentLevel.requirements[type];

    for (var i = 0, vals = obj[type].values; i < vals.length; i++) {
        var val = vals[i];
        if(requirements.indexOf(val) > -1 && cashBalance >= list[val].cost) {
            document.getElementById(val.replace("-", "") + "button").disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Since there's a finite number of possibilities here, typically the most optimized way to handle this would be to completely unroll the loop](http://jsperf.com/loop-unrolling/4).

Comment: @charles: The question already has the unrolled version. He's asking how to shorten code with loops. Not all code needs to be optimized. Sometimes clarity and scalability is more important.

Comment: @charles: Also keep in mind that this code relies on operations that are already very expensive (DOM selection/manipulation). The test you posted is with an extremely light weight operation. So in this case any performance gain would never be noticed.

Comment: to quote, "I'm trying to optimize my code to be more efficient and easier to read." He's wanting his cake and to eat it too. You're achieving the second half of the statement, but moving in the wrong direction for the first.

Comment: @charles Its easier to read, thats accomplished. How come it isn't more efficient?

Comment: @charles: I don't know what he means by "efficient". Perhaps he meant computationally. If that's the case, my original point stands. Any performance boost gained by unrolling a loop will be completely lost in the rest of the performance overhead. A jsPerf probably wouldn't even show a difference. This is the wrong place for such a micro optimization.

Comment: @TommyOtzen: Abstractions nearly always come at a performance cost. But since your operations are already computationally expensive, it just won't make any real difference here. If you're truly concerned about performance, you'll want to decrease your use of jQuery since it's quite slow compared to using the native API directly.

Comment: I updated with a version that drops the jQuery and the `.forEach()`.

Comment: @TommyOtzen: The reason it isn't more efficient is because there's actually an increased overhead, as with any iterator, versus going through each computation separately. The exception for this is in foreach loops where you can take advantage of parallel processing; however, I'm fairly sure javascript doesn't do that within the browser. Yes, it is easier to read, but strictly speaking, it'd preform equal or worse. Shorter code != more performant.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: [You can easily change the forEach code to be asynchronous, and thus perform better on almost all computers](//zef.me/3420/async-foreach-in-javascript/).

Comment: @charles: That would decrease performance overall. When you come across a situation where you have operations that are so heavy that they lock up the browser for a moment, then *maybe* async would be the solution (or maybe just optimizing). And no, JS doesn't do *anything* in parallel. The async merely releases the main thread for a moment to let the UI refresh, thus giving the illusion of better performance and giving a better user experience. Nothing in this question suggests any such need.

Comment: @TommyOtzen: Knowing *how* to optimize and knowing *when* to optimize are two related yet different skills. Using a loop to avoid repeated code in this situation will make no difference at all. So don't worry about this optimization conversation. It's wildly premature.

Comment: NOTE! There is a missing semicolon after `var lists{...};`

Comment: @TommyOtzen: True, though it's not crucial. JavaScript has Automatic Semicolon Insertion. I normally code without semicolons except where absolutely necessary, so sometimes I miss a few when writing code that includes them. :-)